# 2D Divergence Theorem: Question on the integral over the boundary curve

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, divergence-operator, greens-theorem

> Let $\;F=(F_1,F_2)\;$ be a two-dimensional vector field and
>   consider the rectangle $\;\mathcal R= PQRS\;$:

[image]

> If $\;\vec v\;$ is a function which gives outward-facing unit normal
>   vectors to $\;\partial \mathcal R\;$(=boundary of $\;\mathcal R\;$),
>   then by divergence theorem one can get:
>
> $\;\int_{\mathcal R} div(F_1,F_2) \;dx=\int_{SR} F_2\;dx_1
>  -\int_{PQ} F_2\;dx_1-\int_{SP} F_1\;dx_2+\int_{QR} F_1\;dx_2\;$

**My Attempt:**

Searching on google, I found this:

[image]

So, in my case it holds:

$\;\int_{\mathcal R} div(F_1,F_2) \;dx=\;\int_{\partial \mathcal R} F_2 dx_1 - F_1 dx_2\;(1)$

In addition, $\;\partial \mathcal R=(SR)\cup(RQ)\cup(QP)\cup(PS)\;(2)$

Now, combining $\;(1),(2)\;$ and considering the counterclockwise direction , I get:

$\;\int_{\partial \mathcal R} -F_2 dx_1 + F_1 dx_2=-\int_{SR} F_2 dx_1+\int_{PQ} F_2 dx_1-\int_{QR} F_2 dx_1+\int_{PS} F_2 dx_1+\int_{SR} F_1 dx_2-\int_{PQ} F_1 dx_2+\int_{QR} F_1 dx_2-\int_{PS} F_1 dx_2\;$

At this point, I've been stuck. Not only I find some additional terms such as $\;\int_{QR} F_2 dx_1\;$, but also some of the signs are wrong.

I haven't seen boundary integrals since a very long time, so I'm $\;100\;$% sure there's something I'm missing here!

Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This notation is *horrendous*. Just write $F=(F_1,F_2)$, or — better yet — $F= (M,N)$.  For starters, some signs are wrong in the very initial statement. Along $SR$, the unit outward normal is *downward*-pointing, and you should have the integral along $RQ$, not $QR$. Better double-check everything else. I believe you have both the signs wrong in (1). [The Google citation *is* correct, however.]

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your remarks. I edited my notation and the signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those additional terms vanish because they are equal to zero. For example, $\int_{QR} F_2\,dx_1$ is an integral along the vertical segment $QR$; since $x_1$ is constant on $QR$, we have that $dx_1=0$ on $QR$, and therefore this whole integral $\int_{QR} F_2\,dx_1=0$.

Also, as @TedShifrin pointed out in comments, your signs in (1) are backwards. Note that the quote from Google shows $\oint_C P\,dy-Q\,dx$. Matching their notation with your notation, you should have substituted $P=F_1$, $Q=F_2$, $y=x_2$ (the "vertical" coordinate), and $x=x_1$ (the "horizontal" coordinate). But you've got them backwards…

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer! You 've been very helpful! However may I ask you something about the integrals which are equal to zero, just to be sure I completely understood what you said? I should imagine the axes are adjusted so that $\;SR\;$ lies to the $\;x_1$-axis and $\;RQ\;$ lies to the $\;x_2$-axis, right? But still the orientation will be counterclockwise...

Comment: @kaithkolesidou: They don't have to lie on the axes. It's good enough that they are parallel to the axes, i.e. that the sides are horizontal and vertical. Then those integrals are zero regardless of orientation.For example, to find $\int_{RQ} F_2\,dx_1$, you would have to parametrize $RQ$ as e.g. $x_1=b$, $x_2=t$ for $c\le t\le d$ (where $a,b,c,d$ are respective coordinates of the vertices of the rectangle). Then $dx_1=0\,dt$, so $\int_{RQ} F_2\,dx_1=int_{RQ} F_2\cdot0\,dt=int_{RQ} 0\,dt=0$. To go in the backwards direction you will flip the equation for $x_2$, but $x_1=a$ is still a constant.

Comment: Got it now! You've helped me a lot :)